# Why am I unable to update using YUM - using CentOS Stream 8

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, fedora, yum

I'm unable to update any packages within CentOS Stream 8.

I did create two subscriptions at https://access.redhat.com/management/subscriptions

Subscription 1: `60 Day Product Trial of Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server with Smart Management, Monitoring, and all Add-Ons, Self-Supported (Physical or Virtual Nodes)`

Subscription 2: `Red Hat Beta Access`

I have assigned both of these subscriptions to my system, and rebooted. When I attempt to check for updates, I receive the following:

```
[lloyd@localhost ~]$ sudo yum check-update
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Invalid configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:24 ago on Wed 29 Dec 2021 11:45:08 AM GMT.
```

Any advice as to where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like the failover method is no longer supported for EL8 since it has been removed from DNF.

You can remove from the .repo files and try:

```
sudo sed -i '/^failovermethod=/d' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
```